# Suggestion for improving this code to be more readable and easy for beginners?

Tags: javascript, beginner, array, html, html5

I'm a JavaScript beginner trying to learn by doing. Here I have a table with different values: I have used two for loops. Is there an easier way to achieve this? For example having just one for loop, or instead of it use something else? Even better would be if you could give suggestions to improve the code to be more readable (beginner friendly?)

```js
let animals 
let animalCols = ['Animal', 'Animal 2'] 
let peopleCols = ['Person', 'Person 2'] 
 
function myFunction() { 
  paivitys(animals, animalCols) 
} 
 
function paivitys(dataa, arvvoja) { 
  console.log(dataa); 
  //---- 
  if (dataa.hasOwnProperty("animal")) { 
    document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML = dataa.animal; 
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML = dataa.person; 
  } 
  //----   
  if (dataa.hasOwnProperty("animal2")) { 
    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML = dataa.animal2; 
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML = dataa.person2; 
     
  } 
 
  document.getElementById("1name1").innerHTML = arvvoja[0]; 
  document.getElementById("2name1").innerHTML = arvvoja[1]; 
 
  //-----  
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = dataa.id; 
} 
 
function paivitaselekt(dataa, arvvoja) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++) { 
    var valitse = document.getElementById("Select"); 
    var option = document.createElement("option"); 
 
   for (var i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++) { 
    var valitse = document.getElementById("Select"); 
    var option = document.createElement("option"); 
    for (var j = 0; j < arvvoja.length; j++) { 
       option.textContent += dataa[i][arvvoja[j]] + " "; 
    } 
    valitse.appendChild(option); 
} ; 
    valitse.appendChild(option); 
  } 
} 
 
animals = { 
  "animal": "tiger", 
  "animal2": "lion", 
  "id": "54321", 
  "dole": { 
    "Key": "fhd699f" 
  } 
} 
 
paivitys(animals, animalCols); 
let kokoarray; 
 
people = [{ 
    "person": "kaka", 
    "person2": "julle", 
    "id": "9874", 
  }, 
  { 
    "person": "Ronaldo", 
    "person2": "jussi", 
    "id": "65555", 
  } 
] 
kokoarray = people; 
paivitaselekt(kokoarray, ["person", "id"]); 
 
document.getElementById("Select").addEventListener("change", function(event) { 
  const otettutunnsite = event.target.value.split(" ")[1]; 
  const otettutieto = kokoarray.filter((dataa) => dataa.id === otettutunnsite)[0]; 
  paivitys(otettutieto, peopleCols); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    <link 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    /> 
    <link 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" 
      integrity="sha384UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" 
      crossorigin="anonymous" 
    /> 
    <style> 
 
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
  
<div class=""> 
  <table class="table "> 
    <thead> 
      <tr> 
        <th   id="1name1" class="table-success">Animal</th> 
        <th   id="2name1" class="table-success">Animal</th> 
        <th   class="table-success">id</th> 
      </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
      <th id="1name"></th> 
      <th id="2name"></th> 
      <th id="id"></th> 
    </tbody> 
  </table> 
 
  <select id="Select" ></select> 
  <button onclick="myFunction()">backtozero</button> 
</div>  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does. You have currently only described your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

Since you never reassign `animals`, better to declare it with `const`. (On a similar note, don't mix `let` and `var` - `var` has too many gotchas, and `let` permits reassignment, which is more difficult for a reader of the code to parse than `const`. Always prefer `const`.)

You never declare the `people` variable. This will throw an error in strict mode, and in sloppy mode, will implicitly create a variable on the global object, even if the whole script is inside its own function. Best to always declare variables before using them. Since the `kokoarray` is the same as `people`, it'll be easier to just use *one* of those variables, no need for two identical ones which refer to the same array.

Regarding your `myFunction`, [don't use inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have way too many problems to be worth using in modern scripts; use `addEventListener` instead:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  paivitys(animals, animalCols)
});
```

Rather than selecting elements over and over, it would be more elegant to select the elements you need *once*, then reference those variables rather than calling `querySelector` again. It's less repetitive and less expensive.

Numeric-indexed IDs are a code smell. IDs should be reserved for elements which are *completely unique* in the document. If you want to indicate that an element fulfills a particular role that other elements have as well, use a class or a data attribute instead.

Your `<tbody>` is missing a child `<tr>` - both `<td>`s and `<th>`s should only be children of `<tr>`s. Also, `<th>`s should be reserved for *table headers*. For plain data (like in your body), it'd be more semantically appropriate to use `td`s. If you want to make them bold, use CSS for that.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Rather than having `animal` and `animal2` and `person` and `person2`, it'd be a lot simpler to combine all of those properties into a single array property, perhaps call it `names`. Rather than having multiple entirely separate data structures, it'll be far easier to parse it if they have the same format. One option is:

```
const animalData = {
  cols: ['Animal', 'Animal 2'],
  items: [{
    names: ['tiger', 'lion'],
    id: "54321",
  }]
};
const people = {
  cols: ['Person', 'Person 2'],
  items: [{
      names: ['kaka', 'julle'],
      id: "9874",
    },
    {
      names: ['Ronaldo', 'jussi'],
      id: "65555",
    }
  ]
};
```

This way, to reference the first (only) animal, use `animalData.items[0]`. To reference the `i`th person, reference `people.items[i]`. Populating the table gets much easier now:

```
const headTR = document.querySelector('thead tr');
const bodyTR = document.querySelector('tbody tr');
function display(cols, item) {
  headTR.children[0].textContent = cols[0];
  headTR.children[1].textContent = cols[1];
  bodyTR.children[0].textContent = item.names[0];
  bodyTR.children[1].textContent = item.names[1];
  bodyTR.children[2].textContent = item.id;
}
```

Remember to use `textContent` when inserting text - using `innerHTML` when you're not *deliberately* inserting HTML markup makes things slower and can be a security hazard if the input isn't trustworthy.

To identify which person item should be displayed when the `select` changes, you can set the value of each `<option>` to its current index, eg:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">kaka 9874</option>
  <option value="1">Ronaldo 65555</option>
</select>
```

Then, when the select changes, just pass `people.items[select.value]` to the function that populates the table, rather than having to `.find`.

You can construct the `options` much more concisely, like the following:

```
people.items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const option = select.appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
  option.textContent = `${item.names[0]} ${item.id}`;
  option.value = i;
});
```

Put all these together, and you get:

```js
const animalData = {
  cols: ['Animal', 'Animal 2'],
  items: [{
    names: ['tiger', 'lion'],
    id: "54321",
  }]
};
const people = {
  cols: ['Person', 'Person 2'],
  items: [{
      names: ['kaka', 'julle'],
      id: "9874",
    },
    {
      names: ['Ronaldo', 'jussi'],
      id: "65555",
    }
  ]
};

const headTR = document.querySelector('thead tr');
const bodyTR = document.querySelector('tbody tr');
function display(cols, item) {
  headTR.children[0].textContent = cols[0];
  headTR.children[1].textContent = cols[1];
  bodyTR.children[0].textContent = item.names[0];
  bodyTR.children[1].textContent = item.names[1];
  bodyTR.children[2].textContent = item.id;
}

display(animalData.cols, animalData.items[0]);
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  display(animalData.cols, animalData.items[0])
});

const select = document.querySelector("select");
select.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  display(people.cols, people.items[select.value]);
});
people.items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const option = select.appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
  option.textContent = `${item.names[0]} ${item.id}`;
  option.value = i;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="table-success">Animal</th>
        <th id="2name1" class="table-success">Animal</th>
        <th class="table-success">id</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="1name"></td>
        <td id="2name"></td>
        <td id="id"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <select></select>
  <button>backtozero</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for good explanation, i have few questions regarding code i posted, if you possibly could explain: 1: '  const otettutieto = kokoarray.filter((dataa) => dataa.id ===otettutunnsite)[0];  'what is the meaning of '[0]' here ? 2: 'const otettutunnsite=event.target.value.split(" ")[1]; 'what is the meaning of '[1]' here ? 3:'document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML=dataa.person; 'here how it is possible to have access to 'person'? it is array of object and the one above is just object which is this one'    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML=dataa.animal2;'

Comment: (1) `filter` returns an array of items matching the condition. `[0]` accesses the first matching item in that array. It would be much more appropriate to use `.find`, which returns the first matching item directly. (2) The value of the select will be something like "kaka 9874". Splitting by spaces puts `9874`, the id, into the `[1]`st item of the array, so accessing `[1]` retrieves that ID.

Comment: (3) You do `paivitys(otettutieto`, and `otettutieto` is an item in the `people` array (or `kokoarray`), so the first argument to `paivitys`, in the case that an animal isn't passed, will be an item in the `people` array, and those have `person` properties. The `dataa` argument is *not* an array, but an animal or person.

Comment: so it is accessing both 'animal' and 'person' because of these : '  paivitys(animals, animalCols); ' and '   paivitys(otettutieto, peopleCols); '  ?  with the same 'dataa'

Comment: With `paivitys(animals`, your `animals` is an object with an `id` and an `animal` key, so that's what's passed to the function. Your `otettutieto` in `paivitys(otettutieto` is an object with an `id` and a `person` key.

Comment: @ CertainPerformance    is it possible to replace the following with something else 'event.target.value.split(" ")[1]'    "target" is confusing i know there is also 'this' but is there easier way  ?

Comment: `split` takes the string and splits it up on a delimiter, turning it into an array of substrings. I think `split` *is* a pretty clear way to do things. I guess instead of extracting the 2nd word, you could also match the first word preceeded by a space with a regular expression, but that'd probably be *more* confusing for beginners. Another option would be to set state in the DOM so that the ID is retrieved from the option, not from the option's text