# Data selection and filtering

Tags: javascript, array, html, css, html5

Here i have javascript code where is 'animals' object and 'people' array of objects. User selects the data from select box and accordingly table fills with selected data(which is array of objects) and when user wants to reset everything to the state before selected data, user just clicks 'backtozero' button.
the code is a little complicated to understand for beginners specially two 'for loops'(i know foreach but maybe someting else ?) and also information which is inside of 'addEventListeners function' any suggestion for making whole thing easier to read for beginners ? feel free to make changes :

```js
let animals 
let animalCols = ['Animal', 'Animal 2'] 
let peopleCols = ['Person', 'Person 2'] 
 
function myFunction() { 
  paivitys(animals, animalCols) 
} 
 
function paivitys(dataa, arvvoja) { 
  console.log(dataa); 
  //---- 
  if (dataa.hasOwnProperty("animal")) { 
    document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML = dataa.animal; 
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("1name").innerHTML = dataa.person; 
  } 
  //----   
  if (dataa.hasOwnProperty("animal2")) { 
    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML = dataa.animal2; 
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("2name").innerHTML = dataa.person2; 
     
  } 
 
  document.getElementById("1name1").innerHTML = arvvoja[0]; 
  document.getElementById("2name1").innerHTML = arvvoja[1]; 
 
  //-----  
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = dataa.id; 
} 
 
function paivitaselekt(araytassa, arvvoja) { 
 
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < araytassa.length; i++) { 
    var ssellecct = document.getElementById("Select"); 
    var oppttion = document.createElement("option"); 
    for (j = 0; j < arvvoja.length; j++) { 
       oppttion.textContent += araytassa[i][arvvoja[j]] + " "; 
    } 
    ssellecct.appendChild(oppttion); 
}  
} 
 
animals = { 
  "animal": "tiger", 
  "animal2": "lion", 
  "id": "54321", 
  "dole": { 
    "Key": "fhd699f" 
  } 
} 
 
paivitys(animals, animalCols); 
let infoarray; 
 
people = [{ 
    "person": "kaka", 
    "person2": "julle", 
    "id": "9874", 
  }, 
  { 
    "person": "Ronaldo", 
    "person2": "jussi", 
    "id": "65555", 
  } 
] 
infoarray = people; 
paivitaselekt(infoarray, ["person", "id"]); 
 
document.getElementById("Select").addEventListener("change", function(event) { 
  const chosenid = event.target.value.split(" ")[1]; 
  const choseninfo = infoarray.filter((dataa) => dataa.id === chosenid)[0]; 
  paivitys(choseninfo, peopleCols); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    <link 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    /> 
    <link 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" 
      integrity="sha384UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" 
      crossorigin="anonymous" 
    /> 
    <style> 
 
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
  
<div class=""> 
  <table class="table "> 
    <thead> 
      <tr> 
        <th   id="1name1" class="table-success">Animal</th> 
        <th   id="2name1" class="table-success">Animal</th> 
        <th   class="table-success">id</th> 
      </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
      <th id="1name"></th> 
      <th id="2name"></th> 
      <th id="id"></th> 
    </tbody> 
  </table> 
 
  <select id="Select" ></select> 
  <button onclick="myFunction()">backtozero</button> 
</div> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/240745 ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suggestion for improving this code to be more readable and easy for beginners?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240745/suggestion-for-improving-this-code-to-be-more-readable-and-easy-for-beginners)

Comment: Better to edit the earlier identical question to make it clearer rather than to post a new one

Comment: (You could try and use a spelling checker.)

Comment: Dear close voters, whilst the code is a duplicate lets take a step back and actually examine the situation. user222442's other post was closed for lacking a description, this post has a description. This post is on-topic the other post is not. Closing this question will only cause unnecessary grief for the OP and additional work for the community; we'll have to not only close this question but also reopen the other question.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes, but the proper way to handle this would be for the original question to be improved with the updates and go through the reopen process.

Comment: I agree, the proper way to fix an off-topic question is to edit it and enter the re-open process. However since the OP didn't do that; the proper way is to only close off-topic questions.

Answer (score 4):

- Indent your code!
- Naming convention

  - Only use English

    - paivitys -> update -> though really this should be with a subject, so `updateObjekt`?
    - dataa -> data
    - arvvoja -> values
    - paivitaselekt -> updateSelection
  - Dont mispel

    - ssellecct -> selectElement
    - oppttion -> option
  - Use lowerCamelCase

    - infoarray -> infoArray
    - chosenid -> chosenId
    - choseninfo -> chosenInfo
  - myFunction -> this is an unfortunate name, it does not say anything about its functionality
  - The names of your HTML elements id's can be improved
- Dont mix `var` and `const`/`let`
- Don't `console.log()` in production code
- Comments should improve understanding, `//------` does not do that, just use newlines/whitespace
- Dont assign onclick events in html with `onclick`, use `addEventLister()`
- It seems `people` is a global variable, don't create global variables
- It seems you create `people` and `infoarray`, then assign `people` to `infoarray`, and then never use `people` again. It does not seem to make sense